# Getting user's location once, and only once

Tags: ios7, core-location

My app needs to know the *rough* location of a user, with a resolution of their state/province. This way we know what the default tax rate should be in a simple tax calculator. They can still pick it after that, but its always nice to try to get it right.

Is there an easy way to get this sort of resolution without all the rigamarole of callbacks and such? I don't need updates, a single rough location will do, and an old one is likely perfectly fine.

Comment: Some people travel out of the state/province in which they were born.

Comment: And in that case they can select the new one from the pop-up. But 99 times out of 100, our app will be used in the user's "home location", and defaulting to the correct one is a Good Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no short simple ways to get current location.
That means that you need init `CLLocationManager` object, call `startUpdatingLocation` method and retrieve result in delegate method.
It's impossible to get current location synchronously by using one line of code because retrieving location info could take much time (For example turning on GPS sensor and so on.). That's why you get info by asynchronous delegate methods.

Comment: Ugg, OK. But doesn't the system store the last known good position to pre-flight the GPS anyway? It seems that this would be perfect for my purposes.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I've tried it before writing the answer and CLLocationManager.location object returns `nil` object if don't call `startUpdatingLocation` before. Unfortunately it doesn't store last result. I mean situation when other apps got location previously and for new application it returns `nil`. Although it stores last result if your application asked location previously. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location) are details.

Comment: Thanks Visput, too bad about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

is the only way,

but to get a single user position
within the method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` call stopUpdateLocation:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]
```